# Navigation Drawer open close pane not working with smoothness

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[This is my gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR22X.gif). I am using navigation drawer, and I have done some code as per below but the pane close and open is not working with require smoothness.

This is my code:

```
public class SettingFlyout extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public DrawerLayout drawer;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    public NavigationView navigationView;
    LinearLayout viewPager;
    int roleId;

    FragmentStack fragmentStack = FragmentStack.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting_flyout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TextView credits, num_credits, ttlscore, num_ttlscore, tutorNow;

        final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBookRegular.ttf");

        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.student_actionbar_view, null);
        credits = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.credits);
        credits.setTypeface(typeface);


        viewPager = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        int status = i.getIntExtra("status", 1);
        String username = i.getStringExtra("username");


        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        View view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView TVuserName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTextsettingflyout);
        TVuserName.setText(username);

        if (status == 0) {

            roleId = Integer.parseInt(i.getStringExtra("roleId"));
        }


        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        Tablayout_with_viewpager withViewpager = new Tablayout_with_viewpager(status, roleId);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, withViewpager);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else

            if (fragmentStack.size()==0) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                finish();
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            } else if (fragmentStack.size()>0) {

                if (fragmentStack.size()<2 || fragmentStack.size()==2 || fragmentStack.isEmpty()){
                    super.onBackPressed();
                    finish();
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                    SplashScreen splashScreen=new SplashScreen();
                    splashScreen.onBackPressed();
                } else {
                        Fragment fragment = fragmentStack.pop();
    if (fragment.getClass().equals(""))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fragment.getClass().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(fragmentStack.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment).commit();
                }
            }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        Fragment fragment;
        if (id == R.id.profile) {
            Tablayout_with_viewpager tablayout_with_viewpager = new Tablayout_with_viewpager();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, tablayout_with_viewpager).commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.desired_tutor) {

            DesiredTutor desiredTutor = new DesiredTutor();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, desiredTutor).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.payment_options) {
            BuyCredits buyCredits=new BuyCredits();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, buyCredits).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.lesson_tracking) {
            lessonTracking lessonTracking=new lessonTracking();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, lessonTracking).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.TTL_Score) {
            TTL_Score ttl_score = new TTL_Score();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, ttl_score).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.History) {
            History history = new History();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, history).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.notification) {
            Notification notification = new Notification();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, notification).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.support) {
            Support support = new Support();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, support).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.sign_out) {

            pref=getSharedPreferences("loginStatus", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor=pref.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
        else if (id== R.id.daily_game){
            TutorGuides dailyGame= new TutorGuides();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, dailyGame).commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

what should I do to make it smoother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time used this code it not need to use this code every time define in once a time:-

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, desiredTutor).commit();
```

Create a method:-

```
    public static void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String Tag) {
    FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transcation = manager.beginTransaction();
    transcation.replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment, Tag);
    transcation.addToBackStack(Tag);
    transcation.commit();

}
```

and use this  :-

```
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
  {
    case R.id.desired_tutor:
    showFragment(new DesiredTutor(), "");
    break;
    case R.id.payment_options:
    showFragment(new BuyCredits(), "");
    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

You are initiating it everytime. Its wrong. Just initialize it once and use that object to open and close the drawer. remove that code from item selected listener and put it in to Oncreate to initialize it once.

Use below code to make it perfect :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toggle.syncState();
    }


ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };


mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

Comment: Thank you man... i done the code as per ur suggestion but how can i handle open and close event with drawer object???

Comment: can you post video of it if possible